# iOS - sharedApplication is unavailable in Today Extension?

Tags: ios, swift, today-extension, ios-extensions

I am creating a Today extension. I have added all necessary files and getting a bunch of compile errors about

- openUrl is not available
- sharedApplication is not available
- init on UIAlertView is not available

The files with these dependencies are built deep into my app (error handler on my networking layer, etc), and I know that they won't be used in the Today Extension, but in order to completely get rid of dependency in these files I need to refactor the entire app. Is there a way around this?

My code is Swift so I can't use compiler macros either to avoid executing these lines of code.

#if !TARGET_IS_TODAY_EXTENSION
 #endif

Answer (score 5):

You can use compiler macros, though it's not as flexible as with Objective-C (and IMO is slightly mis-designed). If you add something like `-DTODAY_EXTENSION` to the "Other Swift Flags" section of the build settings for the today extension, you can do something like this in code:

```
    #if TODAY_EXTENSION
        println("In today extension")
    #else
        println("Not in today ext")
    #endif
```

It just works. However:

- The compiler seems to ignore macros with a value, so if you use something like `-DTODAY_EXTENSION=1` it won't have any effect. Drop the value and make it `-DTODAY_EXTENSION`
- `#if` works when checking the macro but `#ifdef` does not.

Apple has [some documentation on this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH8-XID_13) but I still had to experiment to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If the code that uses `.shared` is in a framework (ie. cocoapod), then you cannot use compiler macros. There's an approach here that should work: [iOS 8 Extension How To Detect Running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048026/ios-8-extension-how-to-detect-running)