# Is there a way to add `if (iOSApplicationExtension)` condition for `UIApplication.shared`

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I'm trying to find a way of adding a condition for checking *is an extension target* **in Framework** (not main app). Is it possible relying on  `#available(iOSApplicationExtension, *)` with some parameters adjustments?

```
@objc public extension UIView {
    var isAccessibilityCategory: Bool {
        if #available(iOSApplicationExtension, *) {
            return self.traitCollection.preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory
        } else {
            return UIApplication.shared.preferredContentSizeCategory.isAccessibilityCategory
        }
    }
}
```

[How to detect if code is running in Main App or App Extension Target?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048026/how-to-detect-if-code-is-running-in-main-app-or-app-extension-target) - doesn't work, because the framework doesn't know about extension targets

Comment: The `#available` statement cannot be used for detecting target type like application extension. That can only detect what operating system and what version of that OS the app is run on. `#available` was created so that you can use system capabilities that only became available in newer OS versions than your minimum target dependency - such as using Combine or SwiftUI in a project targeting iOS13 <. It cannot be used for running custom logic for app extensions rather than in the app target itself.

Comment: Also, you should not be asking the exact same question after your original has been closed as a duplicate. If you don't agree with the duplicate closure, edit your question to explain why the answers for the duplicate don't apply to your problem and tag the closer in comments so that they can reopen your question if they agree. How come [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29322061/4667835) particular answer doesn't apply to your question? It requires no knowledge from a framework about the app/extension that runs it.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I need a condition that handles `UIApplication.shared` correctly at compile-time, not runtime

Comment: Did you figure out a way?

Answer (score -2):

To solve this problem I created an enumerator with all the app that I created, when the user starts the app I check with the bundle identifier in which app I'm and I save it in the appManager, so after I can perform some changes base the app type also in the framework.

This is my Enum:

```
public enum MyApp: Int, CaseIterable {
    case sysReserved = 0
    case app1 = 1

   public var applicationId : [String] {
       switch self {
           case .sysReserved:
               return [""]
           case .parametersEditor:
               return ["com.team.app1"]
       }
   }
}
```

This my AppManager

```
class AppManager: UIApplication {

   var CURRENT_APP: MyApp = .sysReserved

   override init() {
      super.init()
      getCurrentApplicationInfo()
   }

   internal func getCurrentApplicationInfo() {
       CURRENT_VERSION_NUM = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleShortVersionString") as! String
       CURRENT_BUILD_NUM = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleVersion") as! String
       let appName = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "CFBundleIdentifier") as! String
       CURRENT_APP = .sysReserved

       for app in Application.allCases {
           if app.applicationId.contains(appName) {
               CURRENT_APP = app
           }
       }
   }
}
```