# Reuse a SwiftUI View with .containerBackground(for: .widget) in main App

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit, ios17

I'm working on getting my Widgets ready for iOS 17 and have moved the widget background to the new `.containerBackground(for: .widget)` API.

However I am also reusing my widget Views in my main App, but the container background doesn't render there. I could of course add the background again in the context of my main app with a regular `.background` modifier, but that would result in a lot of duplicate code. Is there a way to render the `containerBackground` in other contexts than widgets?

Comment: You could extract the contents into a separate component and then render it with the background in the widget and without in the main app. No duplicated code.

Answer (score 1):

Same issue and I resolved it by determining when my custom `widgetBackground()` implementation is called from within the app or the app widget extension and thus serving a different background view:

```
func widgetBackground(_ backgroundView: some View) -> some View {
#if EXTENSION
    if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 17.0, *), #available(iOS 17.0, *) {
        containerBackground(for: .widget) {
            backgroundView
        }
    } else {
        background(backgroundView)
    }
#else
    background(backgroundView)
#endif
}
```

Note you will have to change your widget extension targets "Custom Flags" Build Setting to "DEBUG EXTENSION" and "EXTENSION". For a detailed explanation for changing the flag see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66163736.